# Trying to customize Spacy's sentence similarity

Tags: nlp, spacy, sentence-similarity

I am able to generate similarity between two sentences loading spacy's core_lg model trained on Glove vectors.

Now, I want to update some domain specific sentences and assign same vectors to both sentences so that they are treated as the same.

So, how do I add vectors like these on top of the model I am using?

Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: Tried using vocab in spacy to set vectors but didn't seem to work

Comment: see this https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity